# NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all' error coming

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I was web **scraping** a Wikipedia table using Beautiful Soup
this is my code

**Code**

```
URL="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_most-viewed_YouTube_videos"  
page=requests.get(URL)    
soup1=BeautifulSoup(page.text,'lxml')   
table = soup1.find('table',{'class':'wikitable sortable jquery-tablesorter'})    

headers=[]
for i in table.find_all('tr'):    
    title=i.text.strip()    
    headers.append(title)
```

I got Error as

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

I tried using `htmlparser` and `get_text` function also still getting same error even same error for `th` also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to find headers:**

> Go to chrome developer mode and reload your website and go to main url
> and find header tab where all the data related URL will be listed

Using `bs4` you have to add `user-agent`   to get data from HTML and then and table tag return all the values

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers={"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/95.0.4638.54 Safari/537.36"}
response = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_most-viewed_YouTube_videos',headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table',attrs={"class":"wikitable sortable"})
headers=[]
for i in table.find_all('tr'):    
    title=i.text.strip()    
    headers.append(title)
```

Here is the implementation using `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

data=pd.read_html(response.text,attrs={"class":"wikitable sortable"})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using only pandas

```
import pandas as pd
 
table = pd.read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_most-viewed_YouTube_videos",attrs={'class':'wikitable sortable'})[0] 
print(table)
```

Comment: ok but the things is my task is to web scrap this page so i need to web scrap that tabel, the x path which i given that is correct still i am not getting it

Comment: when i tried your code i got ValueError: No tables found

Comment: Try again, I've updated

Comment: yes got it thank you