# Cleaning tags from HTML

Tags: python, html

I want to extract some data from an html file. My problem is the 1st section of code that you see. I cannot do it correctly to erase every tag from the text(`<tr>,<th>,...`)

```
table = soup.find(class_="article-table")
[row.text.split() for row in table.find_all("tr")]
table = lxml.html.fromstring(table)

data = []
for row in table.find_all("tr")[1:]:
    x = row.text.split()
    name = " ".join(i for i in x if i.isalpha() or "-" in i)
    res = [i for i in x if not (i.isalpha() or "-" in i)]
    res.insert(1, name)
```

In the next line of code that you see it removes every single tag but now I don't how to extract only the text that I want.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml').text
```

Any ideas on what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what your problem is. First of all your list comprehension in the 2. row of code is not assigned to any variable? I think you should do something like:

```
rows = [row.text.split() for row in table.find_all("tr")]
```

And maybe this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2935713/13871725) is helpful too.

Comment: I tried the link that you gave me but it know it has an error .line 13, in <module>
    rows = table.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name=='tr')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Comment: You probably have to look into line 12 where you assign 'tables'. In your case bs.find() returns None. Check if the selection in your lambda function is not too strict. Maybe a copy and paste mistake.

Comment: Aight thank you for your time your link lead me to another link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69779741/nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-find-all-error-coming)with the solution

Comment: You are welcome!